# Unity OnCollisionExit() not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, position, collision-detection, raycasting

I have a player object and a ramp called StartRamp. I am using the code below to change my players position and rotation to the surface off the ramp. When my player is off the ramp I want to change the player rotation in the x axis to be only between 50,-50.

But my else statement for when surface is false is not running. Which makes me think my OnCollisionExit() is wrong. Can someone help me?

> Script with following code is attached to player object

```
private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.name == "StartRamp"){
        surface = true;
    }
}
private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name != "StartRamp")
    {
        surface = false;
    }
}

public void playerToSurface(){

    if (surface == true){ // Change Position When On Ramp

        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1.5f) == true)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.green);
            rotCur = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;
            posCur = new Vector3(transform.position.x, hit.point.y, transform.position.z);
            grounded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            grounded = false;
        }
        if (grounded == true)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotCur, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, transform.position - Vector3.up * 1f, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }

    }else{ // Change Position When Off Ramp

        Debug.Log("Player is off ramp.\n");

    }
}

// Update player position to ground
private void Update()
{
    playerToSurface();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be checking if the name `== "StartRamp"` on exit? you have `!=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OnCollisionExit is looking for the collider you *are* no longer in contact with, not any ones you aren't, you should say that the object name *is* startramp, not *isn't*.

```
private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
if (collision.gameObject.name == "StartRamp")
    {
        surface = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had it to that before but my charater physics dont react quite the same

Answer (score 0):

I did this one and it worked fine in unity.

```
private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "StartRamp")
    {
        surface.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: surface is a bool value

Comment: public bool surface; is global variable. In my else statement for surface != true changes the way my player physics and movement work compaired to my if statement. How can i fix that? So that the ridgebody moves the same way but allows me to change the way it is tilted or rotated?

Comment: It is happening with this code. No errors pop up its just the player physics don't work the same as they do with the if(surface == true) statement.       (Problem)----->                                                                                                                                                                     
   else{ // Change Position When Off Ramp

        Debug.Log("Player is off ramp.\n");

    }

Comment: Can u see the bool changing in the inspector?